# subgroup of dihedral group of order 8

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(a, r)$ describe the group such that $a^2=e=r^4$. That is $$D_4=\langle a,r: a^2=e=r^4, ara^{-1}=r^{-1} \rangle$$

Why is $\{ e, r, r^3 \}$ not a subgroup ?

The inverse of $e$ is just $e$ and the inverses of $r^3$ and $r$ are each other.
and $r*r^3=r^4=e$, so isn't it also closed under operation?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ . Anyway, $\{e,r,r^3\}$ is not a subgroup, as it is not closed under multiplication.

Comment: Is $r*r = r^2$ in the subgroup ??

Comment: AH! I see now. Thank you!